# JavaFX Flowpane to New Line

Tags: text, javafx

I have a FlowPane that I would like to go to a new line every time I add a new child (another entry of text)

```
Text text1 = new Text("Here is some text");
Text text2 = new Text("This should be on a new line");

flowPane.getChildren().add(text1);
flowPane.getChildren().add(text2); //should go to the next line
```

This just keeps appending the text next to each other like so:

```
"Here is some textThis should be on a new line"
```

Does anyone out there know of a way to fix this?  It seems like it should be a straight forward part of the API, but I can't find anything relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the api: `A horizontal flowpane (the default) will layout nodes in rows, wrapping at the flowpane's width.`. So basically, by default, all your components will be added in the same row until there's not enough space available.

You want to either change the orientation, or use another layout.